# Converting Dictionary Value to List

Tags: python

I am using the python csv importer tool to import values into a dictionary (and later pass into a templating system). However it imports them all as strings. I need to split one of the values of the dictionary into a list based on a certain delimiter, lets say the '-' symbol.

I imagine my code isn't working because strings are immutable.

CSV File (just an example)

```
firstname,surname,listfield
John,Smith,54-23-34-23-12
Fred,Jones,78-76-54-23-23
```

Code

```
input_file = csv.DictReader(open("import.csv"))
for record in input_file:
    for key, value in record.iteritems():
        if '-' in value:
            value = value.split('-')
```

In my template file, looping through that value simply prints one value at a time (one letter) as it thinks it is still a string.

I thought I could create a new dictionary value as a list to get around the immutable problem but the loop spits out an error along the lines of 'the amount of values in dictionary has changed', which makes to me why that wouldn't work either.

I'm sure there is a easy way to do what I am after and would appreciate any help on this matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a new list of dictionaries.

```
>>> final = []
>>> input_file = csv.DictReader(open("import.csv"))
>>> for record in input_file:
        for key, value in record.iteritems():
            if '-' in value:
                record[key] = value.split('-')
        final.append(record)


>>> final
[{'surname': 'Smith', 'listfield': ['54', '23', '34', '23', '12'], 'firstname': 'John'},
 {'surname': 'Jones', 'listfield': ['78', '76', '54', '23', '23'], 'firstname': 'Fred'}]
```

Comment: Hi Sukrit, sorry for the late reply but I tried that and it worked for me :) thanks for the help :)

Comment: @baz00r: Glad it helped you out.